# Swift array becomes empty after assignment and print shows different results

Tags: swift

I'm facing a peculiar issue in my Swift code where I'm assigning a non-empty array to another array, but when I print the latter, it shows as empty. Here's the relevant part of my code:

```
struct CalendarDay: Identifiable {
    var id: UUID = .init()
    var date: Date
    var data: Any?

    init(date day: Date) {
        self.date = day
    }

    init(date day: Date,date data: Any?) {
        self.date = day
        self.data = data
    }
}

static func fetchWeek(_ date: Date = .init()) -> [CalendarDay] {
    var week: [CalendarDay] = []
    let calendar = Calendar.current
    let startDate = calendar.startOfDay(for: date)
    let weekForDate = calendar.dateInterval(of: .weekOfMonth, for: startDate)
    guard let startOfWeek = weekForDate?.start else {
        return []
    }
    guard let endOfWeek = weekForDate?.end else {
        return []
    }
    //mock get date
    var data: [SomeData] = []
    data = getDataByDate(startOfWeek, endOfWeek)

    for index in 0..<7 {
        if let weekDay = calendar.date(byAdding: .day,value: index ,to: startOfWeek) {
            var w: CalendarDay =  CalendarDay(date:weekDay)
            var d: [SomeData] = []
            //get data
            data.forEach{ value in
                if weekDay.isSameDay(value.createAt) {
                    d.append(value)
                }
            }
            if d.count != 0 {
                w.data = d
            }
            week.append(w)
        }
    }
    return week
}
```

View Struct

```
@State private var showData: [SomeData] = []
@State private var weekDays: [[Date.CalendarDay]] = []
func currentDayHaveData() -> Bool {
        var has: Bool = false
        for i in 0..<self.weekDays.count {
            for v in self.weekDays[i] {
                if self.currentDate.isSameDay(v.date) && v.data != nil {
                    if let data = v.data as? [SomeData], !data.isEmpty {
                        self.showData = data
                        print(data,type(of: data),type(of: self.showData),self.showData)
                    } else {
                        print("v.data is nil or empty")
                        self.showData = []
                    }
                    has.toggle()
                }
            }
        }
        return has
    }
```

The output of the print statement is as follows:

```
[swift_component_ios.SomeData(id: 008D311E-FB3D-4F03-8993-67BEB952A81E, title: "title1", content: "concent20240124", createAt: 2024-01-23 18:38:11 +0000)] Array<SomeData> Array<SomeData> []
```

As you can see, data contains an element of SomeData, but self.data prints as an empty array []. This print statement is directly after the assignment, and there are no other modifications to self.data in between.

I have confirmed that there's no concurrent modification of self.showData, and there are no didSet/willSet observers that might alter its content. The issue occurs within a single function, and I'm not sure why self.data is ending up empty.

Can anyone help me understand why self.showData is empty after the assignment, despite data being non-empty?

What I Have Tried:

I have tried several methods to diagnose and solve this issue:

I checked the value of v.data and confirmed it's a non-empty array of SomeData instances.
I ensured that self.data is not modified anywhere else between the assignment and the print statement.
I attempted the assignment in a different function and scope, but the problem persisted.
I debugged the code using breakpoints in Xcode and observed that self.data becomes empty immediately after the assignment.
Despite my efforts, self.data remains empty after being assigned the value of data.

What I Expect:

I expect self.data to contain the same elements as data after the assignment. However, self.data is empty when printed out, despite data being non-empty.

I'm not sure why this is happening and am looking for any insights or suggestions to resolve this issue.

Comment: Maybe the compiler is confused by so many different occurrences of `data` . Actually you can simplify the code: `self.data = v.data as? [SomeData] ?? []` does exactly the same.

Comment: Why do you need to cast the data with _as?_  Also have you tried to _map()_ your data into self.data?

Comment: I assume this is a bit of a method inside the class. Can you provide a minimized version of the class with just the method and the fragment?

Comment: func currentDayHaveData() -> Bool {
        var has: Bool = false
        for i in 0..<self.weekDays.count {
            for v in self.weekDays[i] {
                if self.currentDate.isSameDay(v.date) && v.data != nil {
                    if let data = v.data as? [SomeData], !data.isEmpty {
                        self.showData = data
                        print(self.data)
                    } else {
                        self.showData = []
                    }
                    has.toggle()
                }
            }
        }
        return has
    }

Comment: I have re edited this issue and added more code

Answer (score 0):

By adding breakpoint analysis in self.showData,Xcode show an error message "Modifying state during biew update,this will cause undefined behavior". So I solved this problem through under code:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.showData = data
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The 'let' keyword restricts the variable assignment to the block's scope, and variables defined with 'let' cannot re-declare a previous declaration of the same variable.  I think what is happening is that as soon as you enter another code block after setting data to v.data, the data variable identifier reverts back to using the previous instance of data declared with "var".

And so you may try changing this line:

```
if let data = v.data as? [SomeData], !data.isEmpty {
```

To read like this replacing 'let' with 'var':

```
if var data = v.data as? [SomeData], !data.isEmpty {
```

If that has no effect then the next thing I would want to check is the definition of the isEmpty() function and make sure that it is handling strict equality properly (I don't see it included here and do not think it is a built in function), as these two expressions are different:

```
data == false
```

may not be equivalent to:

```
data === false
```

I hope that helps, good luck :)